# Contador a partir de um valor

Tags: jquery, data

Olá, estou criando um contador de tempo, para fazer uma barra de progresso de música. Estou usando o seguinte código. Porém, este contador começa a contar em 00:00 como obviamente, mas eu gostaria que ele começasse a contar a partir de um valor que eu estipular, por exemplo: 02:35.

Quais alterações posso fazer para isso acontecer? Já que não consegui.

```
startCounting: function(time){
    start = typeof(time) == 'undefined' ? new Date() : time;

    loop = window.setInterval('aTurn.updateCouting()', 1);
},
updateCouting: function(){
    aTurn.printTime(aTurn.diffProgress(aTurn.getTime()));
},
printTime: function(time){
    $('.atual').text(time);
},
getTime: function(){
    return(new Date() - start);
},
diffProgress: function(seconds){
    if(isNaN(seconds))
        seconds = 0;

    var diff = new Date(seconds);
    var minutes = diff.getMinutes();
    var seconds = diff.getSeconds();

    if(minutes < 10)
        minutes = '0' + minutes;
    if(seconds < 10)
        seconds = '0' + seconds;

    return minutes + ':' + seconds;
},
startProgress: function(){
    if(start){
        aTurn.unstartProgress();
    }
    else{
        aTurn.startCounting();
        return false;
    }
},
unstartProgress: function(){
    clearInterval(loop);

    start = 0;

    aTurn.fillText();
},
clearProgress: function(){
    aTurn.unstartProgress();
    $('.atual').text(aTurn.diffProgress(0));
},
fillText: function(){
    $('.atual').text();
}
```

Comment: Não entendi, você quer que o valor inicial seja 2:35 ou quer começar a contar quando a execução do áudio chegar nesse ponto?

Comment: Quero que o valor inicial seja 2:35.

Comment: Ou o que eu estipular, porquê quando troca de música é outro valor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para fazer o que pretende com o código atual, precisa apenas de mudar a sua função `startCounting` para interpretar um tempo de entrada e ajustar o parametro `start` apropriadamente.

Sugiro que receba o tempo de entrada como `string` formatado em `minutos:segundos`. Tendo em conta isso poderia reescreve-lo da seguinte forma:

```
startCounting: function(time) {
    if (typeof(time) == 'undefined'){
        start = new Date();
    }
    else if (typeof time == 'string'){ //se é uma string então tem tempo de entrada
        //partir os minutos e segundos pelos : e converter para numero
        let [minutes, seconds] = time.split(":").map(Number);      
        //andar a data para trás os milisegundos necessários para fazer como
        //se já tivesse passado o tempo de entrada
        start = new Date() - ((minutes*60 + seconds) * 1000);
    }

    loop = window.setInterval('aTurn.updateCouting()', 1);
}
```

E depois chama passando o valor de entrada como `string`:

```
aTurn.startCounting("2:35");
```

Veja este novo método a correr integrado com o resto do seu código:

```js
aTurn = {

  startCounting: function(time) {
    if (typeof(time) == 'undefined'){
      start = new Date();
    }
    else if (typeof time == 'string'){
      let [minutes, seconds] = time.split(":").map(Number);
      
      start = new Date() - ((minutes*60 + seconds) * 1000);
    }
    
    loop = window.setInterval('aTurn.updateCouting()', 1);
  },
  updateCouting: function() {
    aTurn.printTime(aTurn.diffProgress(aTurn.getTime()));
  },
  printTime: function(time) {
    $('.atual').text(time);
  },
  getTime: function() {
    return (new Date() - start);
  },
  diffProgress: function(seconds) {
    if (isNaN(seconds))
      seconds = 0;

    var diff = new Date(seconds);
    var minutes = diff.getMinutes();
    var seconds = diff.getSeconds();

    if (minutes < 10)
      minutes = '0' + minutes;
    if (seconds < 10)
      seconds = '0' + seconds;

    return minutes + ':' + seconds;
  },
  startProgress: function() {
    if (start) {
      aTurn.unstartProgress();
    } else {
      aTurn.startCounting();
      return false;
    }
  },
  unstartProgress: function() {
    clearInterval(loop);

    start = 0;

    aTurn.fillText();
  },
  clearProgress: function() {
    aTurn.unstartProgress();
    $('.atual').text(aTurn.diffProgress(0));
  },
  fillText: function() {
    $('.atual').text();
  }
};

aTurn.startCounting("2:35");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="atual"></div>
```

Pessoalmente acho a forma como está a implementar excessivamente complicada, e bem mais simples seria armazenar minutos e segundos separadamente. Dessa forma seria mais fácil de interpretar o valor de entrada e também de mostrar no ecrã.

Também não recomendo que deixe o intervalo de atualização em 1 milisegundo caso contrário pesa excessivamente no navegador do cliente sem necessidade.

Comment: Muito obrigado amigo, agradeço de coração.